# Find all email addresses that are 3 characters to the left of the @ sign

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to clean up some old or incorrect email addresses using Powershell. I am trying to locate and eventually remove all email addresses that have 3 characters to the left of the @ sign (ex. abc@SomeDomain.com) I am not quite sure how to do it because the 3 characters can be anything between a-z. Can someone lend some guidance on how I can accomplish this with Powershell.

Thanks-

Comment: `"ab@domain.com", "abc@domain.com", "abcd@domain.com" | Where-Object { $_ -match "^...@" }`. `^` = match start, `...` = match exactly three characters, `@` = match `@`. Tying this in with a statement to get addresses from Exchange is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your example got me closer to what I am trying to accomplish. I found that SMTP: is prefixed to the email addresses in question. So I changed the script to get-mailbox  | Where-Object {$_.Emailaddresses -match "^SMTP:...@SomeDomain.com" }. That seems to give the mailboxes I want. Now I want it to output the specific email address I am looking for with the users name. Keep in mind that each mailbox will have multiple email addresses.